# Orthogonal polynomial integrals vanish

Tags: calculus, analysis

What is meant when an integral "vanishes" over a certain interval?  For example, between $0$ and $\pi$:

$$\int(\cos m\theta) (\cos n\theta)d\theta=0$$

Does this imply there is no area under the curve, and that these two polynomials form a basis?

Comment: How about $\int_0^{\pi}\cos xdx=?$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee:  Do you mean its graph is half above the x axis and half below?

Comment: The integral is zero if $m\neq n$.

Comment: @CuriousGeorge119,  what is the area of $\cos x$ between $0,\pi?$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee:  zero?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=find+the+area+of+cosx+from+0+to+pi

Comment: @labbhattacharjee:  Thanks for the link...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that we don't say that
$$
\int(\cos m\theta) (\cos n\theta)d\theta=0
$$
between $0$ and $\pi$, rather, we say that (assuming $m \neq n$ and both are integers)
$$
\int_0^{\pi}(\cos m\theta) (\cos n\theta)d\theta=0
$$
And those two statements are very different. In fact, to find the antiderivative, we would note
$$
(\cos m\theta) (\cos n\theta) = 
\frac12 \left(\cos((m+n)\theta)+\cos(m-n)\right)
$$
To find (assuming $m\neq n$ are integers)
$$
\begin{align}
\int(\cos m\theta) (\cos n\theta)d\theta &=
\int \frac12 \left(\cos((m+n)\theta)+\cos(m-n)\right)d\theta\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac1{m+n}\sin((m+n)\theta) + \frac1{|m-n|}\sin((m-n)\theta)\right) + C
\end{align}
$$
Finding the difference of this antiderivative between $0$ and $\pi$ gives you zero, but changing the limits will give you a different answer.

Does this mean that there is no area beneath the curve? No.  It means that the positive area cancels out with the negative area.  That is, the positive area (beneath the function) on this interval is equal to the negative area (above the function) on this interval.

Does it mean that these two polynomials form a basis?  First of all, these aren't polynomials.  Yes, these functions form a basis in a sense, but I don't think that means what you think it means.  The fact that 
$$
\int_0^{\pi}(\cos m\theta) (\cos n\theta)d\theta=0
$$
Does mean that, under a certain framework, if $m\neq n$ are integers, the two functions $\cos(m\theta)$ and $\cos(n\theta)$ are **orthogonal**.

Comment: Thanks Omnomnomnom, appreciate your explanation!

Comment: No problem.  I still am not sure what you meant when you said the functions "form a basis".  Are you starting to learn about Fourier Series?

Comment: Not there yet, I'm starting a research project on orthogonal polynomials.  I thought my professor said that (monomial?) polynomials are linearly independent, and naturally form a basis?  She mentioned a basis several times...

Comment: Ah, yes. [She means this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)), then. Have you taken linear algebra yet? It helps to conceptualize functions the way you would think of vectors

Comment: I didn't realize you added more information to your answer... thank you for that Omnomnomnom!!!

Comment: So the basis these functions form is not the same kind of basis in the link?  That is good to know if so.  I did take Linear Algebra, and even though these functions are not polynomials, polynomials are vectors, is that right?

Comment: Well, these function do form a basis, just like in linear algebra, if you think of these functions as vectors. These two functions are linearly independent because the only $a,b$ such that $a\cos(m\theta)+b\cos(n\theta)=0$ for every $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ are $a=b=0$. You can think of these functions as vectors in the same way you think of polynomials as vectors. In fact, you can think of these functions as infinite-dimensional vectors because each has infinitely many values between $0$ and $\pi$. These vectors are orthogonal if you take the integral of the product as your inner product.

Comment: More importantly, these properties extend for any number of functions $\cos n_1\theta,\cos n_2\theta,\dots, \cos n_k \theta$.  That is, as long as none of the $n_i$ are equal, these functions are linearly independent and mutually orthogonal under the previously described inner product.

Comment: Great information and explanation... I really appreciate it, thanks!!!!